# In how many ways can $16$ executives, including two brothers, be arranged around a circular table if the two brothers can't be seated together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $16$ executives, including two brothers. In how many ways can they be arranged around a circular table if the two brothers can't be seated together?

I tried putting each of the brothers in between the $14$ executives by $13! \cdot 14C2 \cdot 2$.

Comment: I see that you are beginner. You must incorporate your thoughts/attempt with the question you ask

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive answers that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Are seatings which are equal up to a rotation considered equal?

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily calculated by substracting the number of ways in which they sit together from the total number of ways

Comment: Is there any other method without subtracting them??..

Comment: I think this is the easiest

Comment: @aneeshcool why do you want another method? This works fine.

Comment: Yes but i tried putting each of the brothers in between the 14 executives by 13!* 14C2 *2

Comment: @aneeshcool solve using the above method and you will get the same answer, I suppose

Comment: @aneeshcool  Rather than placing your attempt in the comments, you should place it in the question itself.

Comment: Yes both the answers are same..thanks bro

Comment: Iam sry for doing it in comment.but iam new to this